# Error running 'app' Unable to determine activity name

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I am working on Android Studio. I have created a Tabbed View Activity by first creating an Empty Activity. When I try to run the project I got the error below. I tried to Clean Project, Build Project, Invalidating Caches and updating the Gradle Version. But I still getting the error. How can I proceed ?
[image: error_img]

build.gradle.kts(Module) :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.yunusulucay.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.yunusulucay.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay"
            >

<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>-->
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>-->

<!--            </intent-filter>-->

        </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ERROR REASON:**
In your AndroidManifest.xml you have to provide default activity. But in your case you have commented out

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

which is needed to be provided to default activity.

**SOLUTION:**
just uncomment or add these lines to your activity tag. Hopefully this solution will work.

Comment: Where is the persistent window where I can see this error in android studio?  Why does it just come up as a "toast".  Where can I click the error to be taken to this line of code?  (in a persistent window?)  How would I know this error is happening in the AndroidManfest.xml file without choosing to write all android apps via SDK WITHOUT Android Studio?